# Left of a character in a string in C#

Tags: c#

How do I get the left of "@" character from the emailID string "feedback@abc.com" in C#

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
string email = "feedback@abc.comm";
int index = email.IndexOf("@");
string user = (index > 0 ? email.Substring(0, index) : "");
```

Comment: What advantages does this have over the slightly more intuitive answer posted by Samuel Neff below?

Comment: This answer is giving some of the "Sanity" checks that Samuel mentioned.  Here he is checking that the '@' character was actually found, if it wasn't, it is setting user to `String.Empty`.  I would suggest to setting back to email since the character needing to be removed wasn't present.  However, this is a great answer.  Provides the solution and additional validation check example.

Answer (score 6):

```
var email = "feedback@abc.com";
var name = email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf("@"));
```

You'll want to do some sanity checks like make sure it's not null and that you actually find the "@" sign.

Answer (score 6):

```
string username = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("feedback@abc.com").User;
```

Answer (score 4):

email.Split('@').Last()
email.Split('@').First()

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) methods:

```
var email = "feedback@abc.com";
var user = email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf("@"))
```

Comment: Lowercase **b** on the string.  `Substring` not _SubString_.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
string email = "test@testdomain.com";
string user = email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf("@"));
```